# Open custom page on the settings click, firefox addon SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using Firefox addon-SDK to create my addon.
I use [simple-prefs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/simple-prefs.html) for the options, but how can I open *custom* page when user clicks on the "Settings" button in the Firefox addon manager?
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. If you have some preferences that cannot be expressed by the simple-prefs system, you could add a button in the preferences of your add-on that can open a custom page in a new tab, or window. See `control` type: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/simple-prefs.html

My suggestion, is stick to the simple-prefs when is possible, because they're synchronized across computers and devices using Firefox Sync.

Comment: Thank you for the help!   If I could use simple-prefs, I would use. But I want generate dyncamic list of options. Is this possible with simple-prefs?  For now I'm using your solution, button(control) in the options.

Comment: Actually you can, cause FireGestures addon (and Tab Mix Plus, and Web Slide Show) do exactly that, though I don't know how :(

Answer (score 0):

## How to Open Custom Page Directoly from Addons Manager

Actually, you CAN do exactly what you want.  This will open YOUR addon's prefs page when you click on the Options Button *right in the Addon Manager* - it replaces the action of opening to the addon's about page.

Credit for this solution goes to [Noitidart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1828637/noitidart).

This is a no-javascript solution, believe it or not.  [The docs are here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#optionsType).  You have to do two things in your `install.rdf`:

1. Set `<em:optionsURL>resource://myAddonID/data/my.html</em:optionsURL>`
2. Set `<em:optionsType>3</em:optionsType>`

[Noitidart actually created a sample addon](https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n/tree/html-options) to illustrate this.  The code is all blank *except* for those two lines in the `install.rdf` which does all the work.

Firefox does all the tab-handling for you.

Incidentally, [there are three options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests#optionsType) for `<em:optionsType>`

- `1`  Opens optionsURL in a dialog box
- `2`  Options are displayed inside the Add-on Manager
- `3`  Opens optionsURL in a new tab (if the application supports that), or a dialog box

---

## How to Open Custom Page from Addons Manager Addon About Page

Also, in the [docs for simple-prefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs#Preference_Types), toward the bottom there is `control` that you put as a preference in *package.json* just like all the other prefs (all this info is directly from that page):

> When the user clicks the button, the function listening to the on()
>   function for this preference is called.
>
> This type requires an mandatory attribute called "label" which is
>   provided as a string. It is used to label the button.

So, your code (as a prefs along with the rest of them within the `preferences` object in your json file) to make that button appear in the addon options area would be like this:

```
{
    "type": "control",
    "label": "Click me!",
    "name": "sayHello",
    "title": "Say Hello"
}
```

And in your main.js, do this to get it to open a custom page (which would be in your `data` directory; or you could use a regular web page address here):

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var sp = require("sdk/simple-prefs");
sp.on("sayHello", function() {
  tabs.open( data.url("myCustomPage.html") );  //<======The KEY
});
```

Remember that `"name"` is the name of the "message" and needs to be the same in both the package.json file AND in the main.js file.

Try it!  It's very easy and it works wonderfully!

---

Comment: Thank you.
If you read the previous answer and my reply, I already use this approach but it's not what I want.
It requires two user actions and does't look native.

Comment: Well, in my opinion, if you go to the Addons Manager and click on "More" and see the addon info there, you are *still* in the Addons Manager.  My answer lets you place a button on that "More" page.  But I guess you want it outside the "More" page.